# Custom font in Vue.js 2.0 NPM package

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, vuejs2

I'm developing an NPM package with my Vue components, so I can re-use them across all my apps and make prototyping process faster.

Almost everything works fine, except for the custom fonts I'm trying to bundle within my package.

This is my building script:

```bash
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name VueBricks ./src/main.js
```

And this is how my main.js looks like:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar/Navbar.vue';

const Components = {
    Navbar
};

Object.keys(Components).forEach(name => {
    Vue.component(name, Components[name]);
});

export {
    Navbar
};
```

This is my Navbar.vue component:

```js
<template lang="pug" src="./Navbar.pug"></template>
<style scoped src="./Navbar.css"></style>
<style scoped src="./Navbar.responsive.css"></style>
<style scoped src="@/assets/css/animate.css"></style>
<style scoped src="@/assets/fonts/cereal.css"></style>
<style scoped src="@/assets/fonts/linearicons.css"></style>
<style scoped src="@/assets/css/styles.css"></style>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'Navbar',
    props: {
        title: String,
        user: Object
    },
    methods: {
        goHome() {
            window.location.href = '/';
        }
    },
};

</script>
```

Finally, I'm importing my module in a test app, and the error I'm getting is my browser is trying to load all my fonts via HTTP, and therefore not finding them.

[image: Error]

However, all my assets seem to be correctly bundled in my output dist:

[image]

How can I load my custom fonts within my Vue NPM components package?

Comment: try this `<style scoped src="~@/assets/fonts/cereal.css"></style>` put a `~` before the path

Comment: @HankX Thanks for your answer, however I'm gettings this error when building:  ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors   

These dependencies were not found:

* ~@/assets/fonts/cereal.css?vue&type=style&index=3&id=2409796d&scoped=true&lang=css& in ./src/components/Navbar/Navbar.vue